# Missing icons in apps menu

Tags: macos

Today I found out that something strange is happening to my Mac OS apps. For example - Disk Utility.

[image: Where are icons?]

The same is with my Finder.

[image: :(]

What kind of sorcery is this and what should I do now?

Answer (score 1):

The same thing kept happening to me in an earlier version of 10.8, but it stopped after I reinstalled OS X from the recovery partition.

The UI doesn't make it very clear, but the Reinstall Mac OS X option just does an upgrade install or repairs the current installation. I have done it twice so far and it fixed multiple issues both times. Just upgrading to 10.9 might also have the same effect.

Comment: Reinstallation is my only hope? Damn.

Comment: You might try Disk Utilities/Repair Disk Permissions, in case somehow the permissions on the graphics files are wrong.